# Use WordPress theme without GULP

Tags: wordpress, caching, gulp

I've taken over the administration of a website. The developer before used GULP to track changes to the theme code. Unfortunately GULP is causing me more problems than it is helping me move forward, so I would like to know if there is a way to take GULP out of the theme again? The previous developer refuses to set up GULP for me. I only have access to the theme directly via WordPress or FTP. So now if I want to make adjustments to the CSS or the theme code, I have to do it on 3 files (that are named the same, but placed in 3 different folders), because the caching/mechanisms of GULP take effect in several places.

Since I'm not familiar with GULP I hope these information are enough for you to help me with that issue.

Comment: Well, if you don't want to learn how to setup/use Gulp then the solution is -as you said yourself- to make changes to the CSS files directly. I don't recommend it though: if the project is inherited by another developer in the future and they do know how to use Gulp, they'll unknowingly overwrite your CSS changes as soon as they try to compile assets with Gulp. Alternatively you could also just add a fourth stylesheet and add your custom CSS there, leaving the other three alone. Or just spend a couple of hours learning how to set up and use Gulp.

Comment: Actually what I was aiming for is to track theme changes with Git/Bitbucket and test them on a local instance of the website to check the compatibility with new updates etc.

I think this would be more convenient than GULP, because no one in the company wants to get into it and I am just a freelancer that doesn't get paid for that.

Comment: Want to post the code on GitHub so we can have a look and write instructions? Installing and running gulp is easiest done with good instructions to follow.

Comment: unfortunately I'm not allowed to post the whole code anywhere. Would it be helpful enough to take a screenshot of the folder structure or only post parts of the code?